# Image upload with PUT method as listed steps by Walgreens API for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, alamofire

I am using "Walgreens Photo print" API to place order from my iOS app.

In this app at last I need to upload image and use the URL of that image before placing order.

So for that Walgreens developer portal has given couple of steps to follow.

Please check the topic "Uploading a set of images is a 4-step process:" in following link

https://developer.walgreens.com/api/photoprints/rest

I have followed that steps, and here is my code.

```
- (void) callMethodToUploadImages:(NSString *)authData andurlString:(NSString *)urlStr imageData:(NSData *)imageData seesionID:(NSString *)sessionID andDate:(NSString *)currentDate{

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
config.HTTPShouldSetCookies = NO;
config.HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever;

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:config];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:urlStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:currentDate forHTTPHeaderField:@"Date"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:authData forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[authData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"100-continue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Expect"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:sessionID forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-amz-security-token"];
[manager PUT:[urlStr stringByAppendingString:@"/myImage_01_30_2015_12154510.jpg"] parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    
}];
}
- (NSData *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)data secret:(NSString *)key {
const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                      length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

NSData * hash = [HMAC base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

return hash;}
```

When I run through this method, it responds me with the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1465cced0> { URL: http://pod-qa.walgreens.com/myImage_01_30_2015_12154510.jpg } { status code: 400, headers {
Connection = close;
Date = "Fri, 08 Apr 2016 07:16:20 GMT";
Server = AmazonS3;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://pod-qa.walgreens.com/myImage_01_30_2015_12154510.jpg, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

When I searched and dig with this error code, I found that the server is simply not understanding the request we are firing.

Please assist me to achieve this task successfully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the limit the headers to the simple PUT structure below:

```
class PUT:NSObject{

let request:NSMutableURLRequest
let session:NSURLSession

init (url: String, auth: String, imageContents:NSData, imageLength:String, sessionID:String, done: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void)
{

    self.request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:url)!)
    self.request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
    let api:APIHandler = APIHandler()

    self.request.addValue(api.getDateString(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Date")
    self.request.addValue(auth, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    self.request.addValue("image/jpg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    self.request.addValue(imageLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    self.request.addValue(sessionID, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-amz-security-token")

    session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPBody = imageContents

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: done)
    task.resume()
}
}
```